# M Split the string and copy to new column

Tags: powerbi

[image]Need some DAX help with the below data.

I have Columns Uniq ID and Controls.

I want to split the Controls column as shown in New Column.

The string will always start with "AON" and a total of 7 characters (i.e AON0913)

Thanks for help[image]

Comment: Are you open to using Power Query, or does it have to be DAX?  PQ going to be better at transforming data.

Comment: I am ok with PowerQuesry as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Power Query solution.  I added comments to understand what each step is doing.

Input Table:

| Uniq ID | Controls |
| --- | --- |
| RIS123 | {AON0913: test 1}, {AON0S18: Safety glasses complying to AS/NZS 1337.1:2010}, {AON0937: Wearing of protective gloves}, {AON0938: First Aid } |
| RIS345 | {AON0913: test 1}, {AON0937: Wearing of protective gloves}, {AON0939: Some SCO's may already have up-to-date vaccinations. }, {AON0938: First Aid } |
| RIS3223 | {AON0S18: Safety glasses complying to AS/NZS 1337.1:2010}, {AON0937: Wearing of protective gloves}, {AON0928: Safety and Compliance uniform Specifications 12-2017 } |
| RIS0456 | {AON0912: test }, {AON0941: controlling test 4321234 } |

Power Query M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    
    //Add an index so we know the original amount of rows
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    
    //Add a column to create a list of Split strings after ":", the trailing delimiter.  This will create a list with multiple rows.
    #"Add Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Split Colon", each Text.Split([Controls],":")),
    
    //Expand the new rows
    #"Expanded Split Colon" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Column", "Split Colon"),
    
    //Filter out any Row that does not contain "AON0"
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Split Colon", each Text.Contains([Split Colon], "AON0")),
    
    //Extract the text after "AON0", which will be the three digits.  Prefix it with "AON0" to create the full string.  This is in case it does not have a leading "{" delimiter.
    #"Extracted Text After Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {{"Split Colon", each "AON0" & Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "AON0"), type text}}),
    
    //Group by the Index that we created earlier.  We will group all existing columns together as well as create a new column with a comma delimited string for our Output
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Extracted Text After Delimiter", {"Index"}, {{"All Rows", each _, type table [Uniq ID=nullable text, Controls=nullable text, Index=number, Split Colon=text]}, {"Output", each Text.Combine([Split Colon], ", "), type text}}),
    
    //Expand our groups
    #"Expanded All Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All Rows", {"Uniq ID", "Controls"}, {"Uniq ID", "Controls"}),
    
    //Remove any duplicated rows
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded All Rows")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Output Table:

[image: Power Query output]

You can remove the Index column after you remove the duplicates if it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI does not have any native functions in the Power query to perform any RegEx operations (which may be most useful here. Please [vote](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=1395c308-7f92-4321-8e35-6cd04d7108bf) ). What you can do is to use build-in option

Column From Examples; You can here type the desired result in a few rows (where you have the longest example - Max AON occurrence.  ) and powerbi should indicate what you want (probably the should use multiple time splitbydelimiter + data.combine function + substring)

[image]